# Getting multiple data and them adding them into multiple database entries

Tags: php, sql, database, multiple-entries

Hi  have made a php script which the user can pick or add multiple entry into the database for example a user can add 10 items at once the 10 area's show but the main problem is that only the last one is added into the database and not all the data into multiple entries and here is the code and its name is final.php

```
      <?php
      if(isset($_POST['multi'])){
      echo "<form action='final.php' method='POST'>";
      $a = $_POST['number'];
      $b = 0 ;
      $c = $_POST['country'];
      $d = $_POST['state'];
      echo"<table border='1'><tr><td colspan='7'>Country:<input type='text'  
      name='country' value='$c'></td></tr>";
      while($a != $b){
      $b++;
      echo "
      <tr>
     <td>State</td>
 <td>Name</td>
     <td>Main Information</td>
     <td>Second Information</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
     <td><input type='text' name='state".$b."' value='$d'></td>
     <td><textarea name='name".$b."'></textarea></td>
    <td><textarea name='info1".$b."'></textarea></td>
    <td><textarea name='info2".$b."'></textarea></td>
      </tr>
      ";

      };
      echo "</table></br>Total:<input type='text' name='total' value='$a'>";
      echo"<input type='submit' name='Add' value='Add'></form>";

      }

      elseif(isset($_POST['Add'])){
          $a1 = $_POST['total'];
          $b1 = 0;
          $c1 = $_POST['country'];
          echo "There is $a1 types in here";

          $cn = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","");
          if(!$cn)
          {
          die('Could not connect:'.mysql_error());
          }
          mysql_select_db("test",$cn);


          while($a1 != $b1){
              $b1++;        
              $state = "state".$b1;
              $name = "name".$b1;
              $info1 = "info1".$b1;
              $info2 = "info2".$b1;

              $sq="INSERT INTO ftable(Country, State, Name, First, Second ) VALUE('$c1', '$_POST[$state]', '$_POST[$name]', '$_POST[$info1]', '$_POST[$info2]')";

              echo "</br>Country:$c1</br> 
                  State:".$_POST[$state]."</br>
                  Name:".$_POST[$name]."</br>
                  Info1:".$_POST[$info1]."</br>
                  Info2:".$_POST[$info2]."</br>";
          }


          if (!mysql_query($sq,$cn))
          {
           die('Error:'.mysql_error());
          }
          echo"<palign='center'>You have added $a to the dbms</br>";




      }

      else{
      echo"<form action='final.php' method='POST'>
      <input type='number' name='number'>
      <input type='text' name='country' value='country'>
      <input type='submit' value='Generate' name='multi'>
      </form>";
      }

      ?>
```

And thanks , would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this on and im only a noob in coding so sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are executing your query outside the `while` loop.  The solution would be to move your `mysql_query($sq, $cn)` inside the while loop.  Also your insert query has `VALUE` instead of `VALUES`, please see the [insert syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html).

```
       while($a1 != $b1){
          $b1++;        
          $state = "state".$b1;
          $name = "name".$b1;
          $info1 = "info1".$b1;
          $info2 = "info2".$b1;

          $sq="INSERT INTO ftable(Country, State, Name, First, Second ) VALUES('$c1', '$_POST[$state]', '$_POST[$name]', '$_POST[$info1]', '$_POST[$info2]')";

          echo "</br>Country:$c1</br> 
              State:".$_POST[$state]."</br>
              Name:".$_POST[$name]."</br>
              Info1:".$_POST[$info1]."</br>
              Info2:".$_POST[$info2]."</br>";

          if (!mysql_query($sq,$cn))
          {
            die('Error:'.mysql_error());
          }
          echo"<palign='center'>You have added $a to the dbms</br>";
       }
```

Note that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, you should look into using [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) like follows:

```
  $a = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['number']);
  $c = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country']);
  $d = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['state']);
```

Also note that `mysql_` extensions are deprecated so you should look into either [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: @user1868185, in that case I've updated my answer.  The mysql syntax was not correct, you were using `VALUE` instead of `VALUES`.  Please try the updated code.

Comment: thanks for that one and i also did something for this on that i used the include in the while function and this worked just fine as the one you also did and thanks again!